# oculta una columna con sus datos cargados

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Hola estoy trabajando con datatable pero deseo ocultar una columna con sus datos ya que no la utilizare, pero no quiero quitarlo por si en un futuro se utilizara esa columna

```
ajax : { url    : "ejemplo" },
        columns : [
            {   "data": "ejemplo1"},
            {   "data": "ejemplo2"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con la propiedad `"visible" : false` puedes ocultar una columna, y con la propiedad `"target" : [position]` donde el valor `position` es la posición de la columna que quieres ocultar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 2 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 3 ],
                "visible": false
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.bootstrap.css">
                        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                
        <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                </table>
```

Comment: Hola por favor, añade una explicación de tu código